# Highlight date if it has an event using fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, fullcalendar

I am trying to fetch all events in my db and highlight the dates that has an event in my UI. For now, I can only do it using static data and in my test code, it display the event name which what I want is to just highlight the date without displaying event name, how can I fetch I achieve it?

```
 $('#calendars').fullCalendar({

height: 395,

header: {
  // title, prev, next, prevYear, nextYear, today
  left: 'prev',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'next'
},
events: [
  {
      title  : 'event1',
      start  : '2019-03-01'
  },
  {
      title  : 'event2',
      start  : '2019-03-05',
  },
  {
      title  : 'event3',
      start  : '2019-03-15'
  },
  {
    title  : 'event5',
    start  : '2019-05-15'
  }

],
eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
    // like that
    var dateString = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    $('#calendar').find('.fc-day-number[data-date="' + dateString + '"]').css('background-color', '#FAA732');
},
});
```

And the result for this one is like this:

[image]

I am planning to use ajax like:

```
events: [
    $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: '/events',
         success: function(events){
             //return the result as  the events data.
         }

    });
],
```

but I don't know how to implement it. This is my eventController;

```
 public function allEvents(){
    $events = Events::whereNotNull('event_date')->get();

    return $events;
}
```

How can I possibly achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
   $.ajax({
         url: "http://yourwebsite.com/events", // complete URL here.. you need to change it
         dataType: "json",
         type: 'GET',
         success: function(data){
           callback(data);
         },
         error: function(error){
          console.log("Error:");
          console.log(error);
         }
    })
}
```

and change controller code to return JSON

```
public function allEvents(){
    $events = Events::whereNotNull('event_date')->get();
    // make sure events data has title and start values returned from the database.
    return response()->json($events); 
}
```

Comment: Should the event title column should be `title` as well as the start? For now I have `name` as the event title and the start is `event_date` (date time data type).

Comment: I change the url to `url: '/events',` and the result is `Error:
calendar.js:33 {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}`

Comment: You need to use a complete URL there.. a public URL.

Comment: I tried to do `url: 'localhost/events' but it returns `GET http://localhost/localhost/events 404 (Not Found)`. Because for now I'm developing in my local.

Comment: Try `http://localhost/events` if this is giving you the events data in return.. OR open the events page in a brower window where you can see events JSON data returned and copy that URL here in AJAX request.

Comment: For column names, you can modify your Laravel code and add column alias to get right data for fullcalendar.. may be something like this
`DB::table('events')->select('name as title', 'event_date as start')->get();`

Comment: It is not returning data because of the error above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190574/discussion-between-satish-saini-and-eem-jee).